# How to redirect all traffic to a single, SSL www using virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have a website (say example.com), run on LAMP setup, with a CA signed certificate from a Mozilla approved CA.

I want all traffic to go to https://www.example.com so that search engines correctly aggregate links AND user experience to be consistent against all clients (Chrome desktop, safari mobile, etc).

So if user requests:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

All of those will redirect to https://www.example.com.

According to [Apache documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL), the simple and safest way to do this using virtual hosts. So I've setup the following in my httpd conf with the following virtual host setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

On Chrome and Firefox on desktop, this has the intended effect. All traffic is successfully sent to https://www.example.com and CA signed cert is recognized (no browser warnings).

However, on Chrome mobile I receive the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID message. In addition, I have Twilio hit this service and I receive the same error from the Twilio service.

Given the above, my two key questions are:

- Why does the above setup generate ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in
  some cases but not all?
- Does the above setup meet the goal of
  making all versions of example.com look like one for the purposes of SEO performance? If not, what do I need to tweak?

Comment: My guess is that your SSL setup is not properly done and you are missing chain certificates, i.e. it is unrelated to the redirect but only related to the SSL setup. Desktop browsers will often fill in missing chain certificates while other clients don't. Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for chain issues.

Comment: In answer to your second question, it does meet that goal. See Steffen's comment for question one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think you're right. Since posting, it has started working on Google Chrome (without further changes) but the Twilio ping still fails because it can't find path to certificate. I checked SSLLabs and it does call out a missing chain issue. That said, I'm a noob on SSL setup and don't know how to fix that. I installed both certs (mine plus the bundle) that were provided by the CA. Do you know where I can get smart on resolving chain certificate issues?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ugh, I'm a meathead. Went back and looked at the bundle cert and realized I'd somehow cut off the first 10 characters of the "-----BEGIN..." line. Fixed and it's working.

Comment: Voting to close since this was a configuration problem and is not answerable.